# Take the average of a filtered column and have the macro display it in a message box

Tags: vba, excel, macros, average

This macro runs through an Excel document and filters out 3 rows.  Right now the macro just stops when the third row is filtered, however I would like to take the average of the third row, which has a dynamic range, and have it displayed in a message box.

```
Sub PriceVerifyMacro()

    Dim retval

    retval = InputBox("Please Enter The Price Book Header")

    If IsNumeric(retval) = False Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a number! Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:="=" & retval

    Dim retval1

    retval1 = InputBox("Please Enter The Net Weight")

    If IsNumeric(retval1) = False Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a number! Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=40, Criteria1:="=" & retval1

    Dim retval2

    retval2 = InputBox("Please Enter The PO Cost")

    If IsNumeric(retval2) = False Then
        MsgBox "You didn't enter a number! Try again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=70, Criteria1:="=" & retval2




    If MsgBox("Would you like to reset the filters?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=70
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=40
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=19
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay. ...Does the above not work? Do you receive any errors, if so, where? Does it run, but not do exactly what you want, etc? Please detail your question/problem more and please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @BruceWayne sorry for the poorly worded question.  I tried to revise it to make it clear what I want.  Everything runs fine, I just cannot seem to find how to get the average for a dynamic range as opposed to finding it for a fixed range.

Comment: @trincot to clarify, I'm using a massive item extract in which I had to hide certain columns to make the document easier to view.  I am trying to get the average of row 70, which is BR

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your question? Could you leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`Range.SpecialCells` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx). Add this after applying the third filter (`Dim` lines can be moved to the top of course):

```
Dim sum As Double
Dim count As Double
Dim avg As Double
Dim cell As Range

sum = 0
count = 0
avg = 0
For Each cell In Range("BR2:BR" & ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    sum = sum + cell.Value
    count = count + 1
Next
If count > 0 Then avg = sum / count
MsgBox "Average is " & avg
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get it in the middle of the code

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$CL$293662").AutoFilter Field:=70, Criteria1:="=" & retval2
For Each cell In Range(Cells(1, 70), Cells(293662, 70)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'this could be improved, why set to 293662?
    'your stuff to get average and msgbox
Next
 If MsgBox("Would you like to reset the filters?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
```